# How to mock an annotated AWS method in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, aws-php-sdk, phpunit

I am writing a unit test and I want to check whether the method `publish()` was called one or more times. This is a snippet from my whole test class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Unit;

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;
use Exception;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @var SnsClient */
    private $snsClient;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->snsClient = $this->getMockBuilder(SnsClient::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function testNoCaseIdentifierSns()
    {
        $this->snsClient->expects($this->once())->method('publish')->with([
            [
                'doc_id' => 1,
                'bucket' => 'some_bucket',
                'key'    => 'test.tiff/0.png'
            ],
            'topic_arn'
        ]);
    }
}
```

But when I run the code above I got the following error:

> Trying to configure method "publish" which cannot be configured
>   because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is
>   static

I guess the problem here is the method in AWS is defined as `@method` (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Sns/SnsClient.php#L53)):

```
* @method \Aws\Result publish(array $args = [])
```

It is possible to mock that method? What I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

After following comments suggestions I transformed my code into the following:

```
$this->snsClient->expects($this->once())->method('__call')->with([
    'Message'  => json_encode([
        'doc_id' => 1,
        'bucket' => 'some_bucket',
        'key'    => 'test.tiff/0.png'
    ]),
    'TopicArn' => 'topic-arn'
]);
```

But now I am getting this other error:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to '__call' when invoked 1
>   time(s) Parameter 0 for invocation Aws\AwsClient::__call('publish',
>   Array (...)) does not match expected value. 'publish' does not match
>   expected type "array".

Why? `publish()` method signature is an array of `args`

Comment: The method does not actually exist. All listed methods are implemented through the magic method `__call`. You need to mock the magic method.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois can you provide me with an example? I am new to PHPUnit :|

Comment: It's the same as any other method, except that the function signature of `__call` is `string $name, array $args`, so you only need to adjust your code to reflect that you're invoking a magic method.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois your suggestion kind of worked but now I am getting a different error and I am not sure what else I am missing

Comment: You forgot the name of the method (`publish`) and don't forget that `__call` receives an array of **arguments** and not the plain argument. Since the sole argument is an array, the second argument to `with` should be an array of arrays (an array wrapping the sole argument).

Answer (score 7):

From the thrown exception, we see that the __call function is called with the name of the target function (i.e. 'publish') and an array containing all arguments. As a result, here is how the mock setup can be updated:

```php
$event = [
    'Message'  => json_encode([
        'doc_id' => 1,
        'bucket' => 'some_bucket',
        'key'    => 'test.tiff/0.png'
    ]),
    'TopicArn' => 'topic-arn'
];
$this->snsClient
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__call')
    ->with('publish', [$event]);
```

Comment: Note the wrapping array of `[$event]`

Must not be `['Message' => 'foo', 'TopicArn' => 'bar']`

Must be `[['Message' => 'foo', 'TopicArn' => 'bar']]`